# How do I check the data type for a single column in Oracle?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I need to verify what the data type of a given column is. I am working with Oracle SQL Developer. How can I write a SQL query that does this?

Comment: https://www.alberton.info/oracle_meta_info.html

Answer (score 1):

Query `user_tab_columns`. For example:

```
SQL> select data_type, data_type_mod, data_type_owner, data_length, data_precision, data_Scale
  2  from user_tab_columns
  3  where table_name = 'TEST'
  4    and column_name = 'COL';

DATA_TYPE       DAT DATA_TYPE_OWNER   DATA_LENGTH DATA_PRECISION DATA_SCALE
--------------- --- ----------------- ----------- -------------- ----------
DATE                                            7

SQL>
```

As it contains much more info, I suggest you query all its columns, i.e. `select * from user_tab_columns`.

Here's the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17110/statviews_2103.htm#I1020277); it lists `all_tab_columns` which has the same description. Difference is that `user_tab_columns` shows columns that belong to your own tables, while `all_tab_columns` shows data about columns in tables you have access to (for example, if someone granted privileges to query their tables).

Comment: Thank you! Silly question, but do I actually write "user_tab_columns" in the query, or is this meant to be a placeholder to be replaced with something else? I am new to this, so please excuse my ignorance :)

Comment: Type exactly like that; try it.

Comment: Why user tab column for just seeing the data type when you have a proper Desc in oracle to check with

Comment: DESC won't help in any procedure you might be writing, @Himanshu. BTW, what do you think DESC fetches information from?

Comment: Yes its a keyword but here as per OP it din require this much deep insights thats my point.

Comment: Sure, no problem, @Himanshu. You can think whatever you want (and give the others the same privilege).

Comment: and also desc itself behaves like a procedure/function etc internally so it doesnt require to be used inside a procedure/function all it requires is to be called via desc

Comment: Thanks for your help guys. I was able to get what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

You should describe the table, view etc for data type and table structure

```
  Desc tablename
```